# ContextMenu causing all other UI Elements to be unclickable

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, user-interface, contextmenu

I have a couple of ContextMenus with the following style:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" x:Key="ListBoxContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border Margin="14" Background="White">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.999" BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have one ContextMenu for a ListBox, and another for a button (Think Chrome type settings menu). If I close the context menu of the button by either clicking the button again, or clicking any where else on the form, bar the ListBox, it closes fine and I can continue using the program as normal. However, if I close the ContextMenu by clicking on the ListBox, I can only use the ListBox until I Click 'n' Drag one of the ListBoxItems, after which I can then use the Close, Minimise, Search, etc buttons.

Image of Window for reference:

[image: Please ignore the actual text :D]

Code for ListBoxItem Click/Drag

```
Private Sub ReferenceListItemMouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    Dim PW As MainWindow = Window.GetWindow(MainPage)
    StartPoint = e.GetPosition(Nothing)
    PW.Resizing = False
End Sub

Private Sub ReferenceListItemMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim PW As MainWindow = Window.GetWindow(MainPage)
    If PW.Resizing = False Then
        Dim MousePosition As Point = e.GetPosition(Nothing)
        Dim Difference As Vector = StartPoint - MousePosition
        Dim StopDrop As Boolean
        If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed AndAlso (Math.Abs(Difference.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance Or Math.Abs(Difference.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance) Then
            Dim LB As ListBox = ReferenceList
            Dim UIE As UIElement = LB.InputHitTest(MousePosition)
            If UIE IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim Data As Object = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
                While Data Is DependencyProperty.UnsetValue And UIE IsNot Nothing
                    Data = LB.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(UIE)
                    If Data Is DependencyProperty.UnsetValue Then
                        UIE = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(UIE)
                    End If
                    If UIE Is LB Then
                        StopDrop = True
                    End If
                End While
                If Data IsNot DependencyProperty.UnsetValue Then
                    StopDrop = False
                End If
            Else
                StopDrop = True
            End If
            PW.TempItem = LB.SelectedItem
            Dim FN As String = PW.TempItem.PropLastName & ", " & PW.TempItem.PropFirstName.Substring(0, 1)
            Dim TT As String = PW.TempItem.PropTitle
            Dim YR As String = PW.TempItem.PropYear.ToString
            Dim ReferenceText As String = FN & " " & YR & ", " & TT
            Dim DragData As DataObject = New DataObject(DataFormats.StringFormat, ReferenceText)
            If DragData IsNot Nothing And StopDrop = False Then
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender, DragData, DragDropEffects.Copy)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I have a hunch that its the MouseDown and MouseMove events that are causing this issue. If anyone can spot the problem or needs further information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its OK. I fixed the problem. What I did, get rid of the UIElement while statement and associated code. I then replaced this with a simple TryCast(sender, ListBoxItem). If you require a more detailed explanation please let me know and I will get back to you.